# Asterisk precision specification not working with cygwin

Tags: printf

I am using the following C++ code with the Cygwin gcc compiler collection:

```
void WINAPI debugEnterFunction( LPCSTR pszFunction, LPCSTR pszSrcFile, int nLineNo )
{
char szFunction[128];
sprintf( szFunction, "%.*s\t%s:%d\r\n", 124 - lstrlen( pszSrcFile ) - log10( nLineNo ), pszFunction, pszSrcFile, nLineNo );
// More code goes here.
}
```

The program crashes while executing the sprintf statement for the first time, where the argument corresponding to the asterisk specification is 108. If I change the length of szFunction from 128 to 1028, it still crashes. If I change the sprintf statement to the following:

```
sprintf( szFunction, "%.80s\t%s:%d\r\n", pszFunction, pszSrcFile, nLineNo );
```

then it works fine.

Are there any problems or issues relating to the use of the asterisk precision specification with the Cygwin gcc compiler collection? According to the GNU website, the asterisk precision specification should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, never mind; I figured it out.

I had to change the sprint statement to

```
sprintf( szFunction, "%.*s\t%s:%d\r\n", 124 - lstrlen( pszSrcFile ) - (int) log10( nLineNo ), pszFunction, pszSrcFile, nLineNo );
```